# Angular 2+ : Condition based on previous index date value ngIf NgFor

Tags: html, angular, indexing, angular2-template, angular-ng-if

Trying to format a table using Angular where:

If the day of the month changes, then you insert a new row which just contains the date (but also displays the data for that index value immediately below). If the day of the week is the same as before continue inserting the rows.

1) Clearly my code for accessing previous value in index is wrong but I can't seem to find anything clearly which helps.

2) I realise that my current code would compare the full datetime value and not just the day of the month (or week) but I am unsure how to do this in this scenario.

3) when the day changes and I try and insert the date line, I cannot get an additional new row formatted correctly which includes the data for that index value. I have tried playing around with various  and  combinations.

Please could someone help correct this code or point me in the right direction

Thanks

```
<table class="table-striped">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <td>day</td>
            <td>time</td>
            <td>region</td>
            <td>event</td>
            <td>period</td>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr *ngFor="let eco of eco_r ; let i = index"> 

        <template [ngIf]="eco.date != eco[i-1].date">
            <td colspan="5">{{eco.datetime| date:'longDate' }}</td>
          <tr>   
            <td>{{eco.datetime | date:'EE'}}</td>
            <td>{{eco.datetime | date:'shortTime'}}</td>
            <td>{{eco.region}}</td>
            <td>{{eco.event}}</td>
            <td>{{eco.period}}</td>
          </tr>
        </template>

        <template [ngIf]="eco.date == eco[i-1].date">
            <td>{{eco.datetime | date:'EE'}}</td>
            <td>{{eco.datetime | date:'shortTime'}}</td>
            <td>{{eco.region}}</td>
            <td>{{eco.event}}</td>
            <td>{{eco.period}}</td>
          </template>

        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

------------UPDATE ---------------

Following @Iancovici comments I have revised the following

i) corrected to reference `eco_r[i-1].date`

ii) Changed sql source to provide eco.day_of_month and eco.week_of_year to make it easier to reference and check conditions

iii) updated code to only check previous value when `i > 0`

I am still unable to get it to display a new line with the date AND also include the data for that value of `i` on a separate row where it formats correctly. Utilising  as in my revised code puts all 5 values into the first column of the next row and messes put the table format.   How should I resolve this please?

Thanks

```
  <template [ngIf]="i >0 && eco.day_of_month != eco_r[i-1].day_of_month">
        <tr><td colspan="5">{{eco.datetime| date:'longDate' }}</td>
        </tr>
            <tr> <td>{{eco.datetime | date:'EE'}}</td>
                 <td>{{eco.datetime | date:'shortTime'}}</td>
                 <td> {{eco.region}} </td>
                 <td>{{eco.event}}</td>
                 <td>{{eco.period}}</td>
            </tr>
         </template>
```

Comment: If you're still having trouble, can you share your eco array?

Comment: Yes just having trouble with the table displaying correctly now. I've tried playing around with various `<tr>` combinations but can't solve it. What is the easiest way to share the array?

Comment: `eco_r = {datetime: '', data: '', region '', ... }, ..., {... }`

Answer (score 3):

Should probbly be `*ngIf` not `[ngIf]` in general. But I see in your case it’s ok because you’re using an ng template which means instead of directive *ngIf it’s not a bonded property [ngIf]

Also you're accesing the same instance, should access index of array instead so.. 
change from

```
*ngIf="eco.date == eco[i-1].date">
```

to

```
*ngIf="eco.date == eco_r[i-1].date">
```

#### Update: Two more notes

- Make sure you create a table, with  tag
- Don't be afraid to use paranthesis if conditonal expressions become more complex, so you can distinguish the two conditions.

Try this without the filters, then integrate the filters in.

```
<table>
  <div *ngFor="let eco of eco_r; let i = index">
    <div *ngIf="(i > 0) && (eco.day_of_month != eco_r[i-1].day_of_month)">
      <tr>
        <td colspan="5">{{eco.datetime }}</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>{{eco.datetime }}</td>
        <td>{{eco.datetime }}</td>
        <td> {{eco.region}} </td>
        <td>{{eco.event}}</td>
        <td>{{eco.period}}</td>
      </tr>
    </div>
  </div>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks for point out the 'eco_r' point. Am i accessing the previous value of the array in the correct way here then?  `eco_r[i-1].date` 

I tried updating to `*ngIf` but for some reason it doesnt work for my code whereas `[ngIf]` does.

Comment: No error, it just doesnt load anything when I refresh the page after saving the code.

Comment: It's hard to help when you havent exposed your typescript section. But this could be because the first comaprison fails, at index 0 you're comparing with -1 (undefined). Either way, I recommende debugging with console.log, create a for loop in your ngOnInit or constructor, and console.log each date (`console.log[i]`), then console.log a comparison (`console.log( data[i] == date[i-1]`). You might have to use a method to really compare the dates, i.e. `date[i]. getTime() == date[i-1].getTime()`